# for loop working outside, but not inside a function in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I wrote this simple for loop within a function

```
cumulatief<- function(df){
df["cumul1"]<- 0
df$cumul1[1] = 1
y <<- 1
for (i in 2:nrow(df)) {
  if (df[i,12] == df[(i-1),12]){
    y <- y + 1
    df$cumul1[i]<- y
  } else { 
    df$cumul1[i] = 1
    y <- 1
  }
}
}
```

It takes a dataframe, creates a new column, and fills this column with a ranking according to the value inside another column. If it encounters a new value (which indicates a new group) it re-starts ranking from 1.

example:

```
   12 cumul1
1  1    1
2  1    2
3  1    3
4  1    4
5  1    5
6  2    1
7  2    2
8  2    3
9  2    4
10 2    5
```

This is one of the first functions I wrote, and my question is:
if I just run the code without the function wrapper, it works. However, it stops working when i wrap it in a function (it creates a column full of 0, and thats it)

I have been stuck on this for half a day, any help woud be welcome!

Comment: Hard to say the source of the problem without a `df` example to reproduce it, but my guess is the `y <<-` which is generally not used. For what it's worth, you can get the desired result with the data.table package, `library(data.table); DF$new_col = rowid(rleid(DF$value_col))`.

Comment: Same as @Frank regarding `<<-`. My problem is what you mean by "doesn't work". If you want to return the value `y` you must have it in the last line of the function. Just before the closing `}`, add an instruction with the single character `y` .

Comment: I added an example code of what I want it to do, right now it fills 'cumul1' with 0's. I use the Y as the ranking number it needs to fill into the column. As you can see, it resets Y to 1 when it hits a new group in column 12.

I hope this clarifies it a bit!  

Wouldn't franks option keep on ranking and not reset according to column 12?